# Scroll only listview, not other div?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

How can I set if user scroll on listview, the other div outside listview no need to be scrolled too? I can't get any reference to do this out there.

Answer (score 5):

Put your list within a DIV container. Give the container a max-height and make it scrollable:

```
<div class="listCont">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>

.listCont {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y0oLj2vy/1/)**

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is the trick to make it scrollable on webkit touch devices.

Comment: Do I need to define max-height to make it work? If I set it to auto, it seems doesn't work how it should be..

Comment: @Rendy, if you want a scrollable container, you have to either set the height or max-height. I set max-height so it would shrink if the list is short. You can just set the height if you don't want it to change. If you don't set the height, the container just matches the height of the list and defeats the whole point of getting it to scroll.